# Why wont this Spotify "Creating an Artist Page" Example work in JSFiddle?

Tags: javascript, spotify, jsfiddle

I am trying to replicate this Spotify JSFIDDLE example, but it does not work the way the tutorial instructs.

Any idea why it wont work, and how to get it to work?

https://beta.developer.spotify.com/documentation/widgets/guides/creating-an-artist-page/#creating-a-discography

Comment: Can you post a link to your fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/trueliu/bxjj7Lxg/7/

Answer (score 1):

The search query is returning a 401 (unauthorized) error message.

This appears to be because Spotify changed their authorization to a more strict one in 2017. The tutorial you linked is now outdated. To use the API, you need to authorize the request as described here:

https://beta.developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#authorization-flows

Comment: I have also reported this as a bug to spotify (they should either update or delete the tutorial)